# memory address of numpy elements

Tags: python, numpy, memory-address

See the code snip below

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
b = a[1]
id(a[1]) == id(b) # True
```

it is easy to understand because address of `b` and address of `a[1]` is the same. So if I change element in a `a += 1`, element in b will changed as well `b == [4, 5]`.

However, if I changed to numpy array, the thing is different

```
c = numpy.array(a)
d = c[1]
id(c[1]) == id(d) # False
```

However, if I change element in c `c +=1`, elements in `d` will change too (d will change to `array([4, 5]`)), I do not understand two things, 1. why address of `d` and address of `c[1]` is different? 2. if the address is different, why the elements changed simutanously?
Anyone could explain? Thanks

Comment: `c= np.array(a)` will create a new array in the memory,it is not refrenced to `a`

Comment: My guess is that `numpy.array.__getitem__` returns a new *representation* of the item everytime. A proxy, if you wish.

Comment: Look at the flags of `d`.  It doesn't own it's memory (so changes are reflected), and its `.base` is `c`, but due to the nature of how numpy stores data, each time you slice numpy creates a new "view" of the data you need.

Comment: This link might help you: [Numpy Views vs Copies](https://www.jessicayung.com/numpy-views-vs-copies-avoiding-costly-mistakes/).

Comment: `ndarray` does not store its data in the same way as a `list`. `id` is virtually useless in this context.  Read the intro docs for numpy.

Comment: You are looking at the `id` of the `array scalar` in this `numpy` docs page, https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.html

Comment: Be aware that `id` isn't really returning memory addresses; it's returning an integer guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of the object. CPython happens to use memory addresses as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the inner `ndarray` of an `ndarray` is accessed via indexing like you did with `c[1]`, a new `ndarray` is created on the fly as a memory (buffer) view. In this line `id(c[1]) == id(d)`, `c[1]` and `d` are two individual `ndarray` instances whose `data` fields point to the same memory address (called "data area" in numpy doc). Consider the following:

```py
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
c = np.array(a)
d = c[0]
e = c[0]
f = c[1]
print(id(d) == id(e)) # False
print(d.__array_interface__['data'][0] == e.__array_interface__['data'][0]) # True
print(d.__array_interface__['data'][0] == f.__array_interface__['data'][0]) # False
```

The location of the data held by each `ndarray` can be found in the [array interface](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.interface.html). And because `d` and `e` point to the same data at the same memory address, the data address will be identical. Conversely, `d` and `f` do not point to the same data, so their pointers are different.

Comment: however, id(d.__array_interface__['data']) == id(e.__array_interface__['data']) returns false as well, how to prove that they point to the same data?

Comment: The pointer is at `d.__array_interface__['data'][0]` not `d.__array_interface__['data']` and it is an integer memory address. `d.__array_interface__['data']` is a tuple of `(memory_address, readonly)`. These integers are *already* ids, and you shouldn't use `id()` to compare them. What you did by `id(d.__array_interface__['data']) == id(e.__array_interface__['data'])` is comparing the identifiers of the tuples that hold the addresses, which is non-sense.